# How to centre a tr inside div

Tags: jquery

I have a div with overflow-y:auto, and height of X.
inside there is a table with rows and a row with ID = Y, I want to centre the row Y in the middle of the view port of the div.
how do I do it in Jquery? code:

```
<div id="outerDiv" style="height:200px;overflow-y:Auto;">
    <table id="innerTable" >
       <tr><td> ....</tr>
       <tr><td> ....</tr>
       <tr><td> ....</tr>
       <tr><td> ....</tr>
       <tr id="centerMe"><td> ....</tr>
       <tr><td> ....</tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you HAVE TO USE a table?

Comment: tables are not evil, they are good for rows data;

Comment: Are you talking about horizontal centre or vertical centre (or both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the [scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin. This makes it pretty easy to scroll a container so a specific item is showing.

Comment: I've used it, but the container div scroll to the top of the raw, I want the raw to be at the vertical middle of the Div height.

Comment: See the offset option; you should be able to use the height of the container / 2 as a y offset.

Comment: I'm looking for the calculation, not the method.

Comment: General centering logic: `(container.height() / 2) - (row.height() / 2)`. If you use scrollTo and use this as the offset, that should be centered.

Comment: so it's $('#Container').scrollTo($('#middle_raw'), 'slow', { offset: { y: $('#middle_raw'),height() / 2 } });

Comment: $('#Container').scrollTo($('#middle_order'), 'slow', { offset: { top: -$('#Container').height()/2 } });
was the answer, 10x